# Adobe Air app stucks after being in background (or inactive) to much time

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management, air, operating-system

We have an air application (native for windows) that after being unused or background for about some hours after you try to use it it got stuck and "not responding" windows message.

No log or error or crash just got stuck.

The best behaviour that we have got is that after some seconds it unstucks but then stucks and unstucks every 30 seconds aprox, so it is anusable.

We have tried some "ugly" tricks like after being out of focus/background for some minutes, goes into front, it goes, but this haven't resolved the above problems.

I understand clearly, that SO (Windows) has removed the cached memory pages associated to this process, however, this is normal for each program, so,  it is normal that program (specially visually heavy like ours) come back to use, it takes some seconds to go into memory again. 
However after that time of re caching into memory any programs (most) works like a charm.
This is not the case of air app.

is there any trick or recommendation for fixing this?

Maybe we should combine the "to front" trick with some other "dumb processing" to keep the program in memory?

thanks in advance.

Comment: We are not using flex, is there any way to set this property without using flex? It has to be right?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768252/adobe-air-applications-slow-response-after-idle-time?rq=1

Comment: This shouldn't happen normally, but finding the cause is difficult without knowing more about the program, what does it do and how. It probably hangs because some part of context it depends on is lost. First step should probably be a truckload of traces to find out what's going on.

Comment: Did you check if you have a memory leak? Did you analyse with Adobe Scout?